# Calculating length of a line in turf

Tags: gis

I'm begining to work with turf an leaflet and I found my first problem, I need calculate the length of a polyline whit this style:

[image of my line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKzx4.png)

However I can't calculate his length with the function gives turf:

turf.lineDistance(line, 'kilometers');

This doesn't nothing, line is Linestring in the examples but my line is MultilinestriNg, will be for this?, 
thanks, I hope good comments :)

Answer (score 0):

turf only accept "LineString" for this action.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/turf-line-distance

You need convert your "Multilinestring" to "LineString" for example using Qgis.

Comment: Thank you fpr you answer, I did that however the function doesn´t read the linestring converted in Qgis. :(